# Hide posts based on tags using a checkbox in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

Okay, so I am making a fitness website, and on one of my pages, I have all of the posts that have the tag "workout" being displayed. On the left hand side of the page, I have a list of tags that will be associated with the posts, and I want them to be used as a filter. For example, if the abdominal check box is check, all posts that do not have the abdominal tag disappear from the results.

For a visual, this is the site: http://wpdev.connectionsquad.com/fitness/workouts/

I think I know how to filter the posts based on tags using this code:

```
<?php
$args=array(
'showposts'=>10,
'tag__not_in' => array('4','6'),
 );
query_posts($args); ?>
```

But I do not know how to make this code active only when a specific checkbox is checked. I know how to do this using jquery. I have done something similar in the past. For the full effect and not just the visual, this is exactly what I am looking for: http://mihealthandfitness.org/Fitness/WorkoutFinder.html

The code I have for each check box is

```
<li class="clearfix">
    <h4>Abdominals</h4>
    <input id="" name="" type="checkbox" value="" />
</li>
```

Instead of using jquery, I am looking to do it using php.

Comment: You know how to filter and how to do it using `jQuery` then what is your question or where have you been stucked ?

Comment: Sorry,I am looking to do it using php instead of jquery. The other site is not done using a CMS, and I am currently moving it over that way

Answer (score 2):

To utilize the WordPress framework, i.e. PHP only, try:

```
$YOUR_TAG = 'Abdominals';
query_posts('tag='. $YOUR_TAG .');
```

The $YOUR_TAG variable should correspond with the appropriate tags that you have for the corresponding posts.  See the [docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) for more information.

Comment: Right, so that part I can get, but I need to know how to associate that with a checkbox that is checked.

Comment: Since you're wanting to do that via PHP only then you would want to attach a page reload to the `onclick` event for the checkbox, which would use JavaScript.  Within that action, you would pass the corresponding tag value, which will then be parsed on the page load via PHP.

Comment: Okay, I just had a thought, is it possible to list the tags of a post as a class for the container div using php? Because then I could just use the jquery I already have.

Comment: Yes.  That would be a good route and would handle what you're wanting.  The key is that you have to interact with the client somehow, which is why only PHP isn't really feasible in this scenario.

Comment: Do you know how I would accomplish adding the tags as a class using php then? Can you just put the `<?php wp_get_tag() ?>` inside the class for div?